# How do I find text within a file and have it search multiple subfolders?

Tags: find, grep, search

I'm looking for a function name and the folder structure is deep and there are a lot of files to look though.

Usually I go with something like `find * | grep functionname` but is that the best way?

Comment: Duh what? `find` only finds file **names**, not contents.

Comment: Ever heard of `xargs`?  Or the `-exec` primary in `find`?

Comment: Hey man, I said that's what I used, not that it worked! Why do you think I'm asking? Plus, it was "something like" because I could never get it to work and had to google around for the xargs part.

Comment: Sorry, that remark was directed at @Hello71.  I'm still getting used to StackExchange etiquette.

Comment: Take a look at this post:http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2014/03/searching-multiple-strings-in-multiple.html

Comment: find * is always a bad idea.   See the section "NON-BUGS" at http://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Answer (score 15):

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep foo
$ grep -r foo . # GNU grep only
```

and in `zsh` with `setopt extendedglob`,

```
$ grep foo **/*(.)
```

Comment: Better: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep /dev/null foo`, so that `grep` always prints the matching file name. Or `find . -type f -exec grep /dev/null {} +`, for implementations that have caught up with POSIX.2004 (which excludes OpenBSD at the moment).

Comment: Still can't believe there isn't an easier way to do this. And I tried the "grep -r" and it didn't work. Why is it only GNU grep only and why isn't that on more systems?

Comment: Because traditional `grep` didn't have it (the idea was that if you wanted recursion, you used `find` with `grep`) and adding it after the fact to systems that have been working for years could break things.  (GNU `grep` doesn't behave quite identically to e.g. System V `grep`.)

Answer (score 5):

There's also [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/), which is designed specifically for this kind of tasks and does subfolder search automatically.

Comment: An there is also [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) which is way faster than `ack`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the `find | xargs` responses, you might consider using [ctags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) since you say you are searching not for text, but specifically for function names.

To do this you would run `ctags` against your source to create a `TAGS` file, and then run your `grep` against the `TAGS` file which will spit out lines in the following format:

```
{tagname}<Tab>{tagfile}<Tab>{tagaddress}
```

Where `tagname` will contain the function name, `tagfile` is the file it is in, and `tagaddress` will be a vi command to get to that line.  (Could be a just a line number.)

(Is there an easy way to do something similar with the various indices that eclipse builds, or to just query the eclipse database?)

Answer (score 1):

what's wrong with `grep -r` (== `grep --recursive`)?  Am I missing something here?

(+1 for `ack` too -- I regularly use both)

edit:  I found an excellent article detailing the possibilities and pitfalls if you don't have `GNU grep` [here](http://aplawrence.com/Unixart/recursivegrep.html).  But, seriously, if you don't have `GNU grep` available, getting `ack` is even more highly recommended.

Comment: Yeah, apparently not everyone has the fancy version of grep.

Comment: @tooshel - didn't realise the non-GNU `grep` doesn't have that option.  updated my answer :)

Comment: -bash: ack: command not found

Comment: Okay, I read the instructions to install ack . . . and I just tossed it in /bin so everyone can use it. Was that a bad idea?

Comment: @tooshel: only if you don't want everyone to be able to use it...!

Answer (score 0):

`$ find -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 grep foo`

`-r` in `xargs` avoids executing the command if there wasn't input. It's a GNU extension.

There is also [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) which is specifically designed for this and way better than `ack`. It's available in recent Debian/Ubuntu versions in package [*silversearcher-ag*](http://packages.debian.org/silversearcher-ag).

Answer (score 0):

`find . | xargs grep` will fail on filenames with spaces:

```
> echo test > "a b c"
> find . | xargs grep test
grep: ./a: No such file or directory
grep: b: No such file or directory
grep: c: No such file or directory
```

Note that even -print0 has this problem.

It's better in my opinion to use `-exec grep` with find which will handle all filenames internally and avoid this problem:

```
> find . -exec grep test {} \;
test
>
```

Comment: `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …` copes with arbitrary file names. All POSIX.2004-compliant implementations of `find` allow `find … -exec … {} +`, which invokes the command with multiple files at once. A better command is `find . -type f -exec grep test /dev/null {} +`; the addition of `/dev/null` is so that `grep` will consistently print the file name when it finds a match.

Answer (score 0):

If your disks are fast you may want to parallelize the grep:

```
find . -type f -print0 | parallel -0 grep foo
```

Watch the intro video to learn more about GNU Parallel: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ