# Finding files containing certain strings under a directory

Tags: command-line, grep, find

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find text within a file and have it search multiple subfolders?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9125/how-do-i-find-text-within-a-file-and-have-it-search-multiple-subfolders)

I would like to find out all the files under `mydir/` directory whose content contains the string "**apple**". How can I do this?

Comment: This has been covered before. Have you performed a search before asking?

Comment: Yes, I tried "gerp "apple"" but it search for all the files in my Ubuntu system which takes a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe one of those

```
cd mydir ; grep -lr apple *
```

or

```
find mydir -type f | xargs grep -l apple
```

Comment: What does * starnd for in command "grep -lr apple * "?

Comment: * is target of grep command. It will expand to every name in current folder.

Comment: It is funny, when I execute the command `find . -type f | xargs grep -l t\.test` in a directory it will work and when I apply the same command on the parent directory, it returns _xargs: unterminated quote_

Comment: Maybe, you have files with quotes or blanks in the name.

Using "find mydir -type f -exec grep -l apple '{}' \;" might help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `find` actually, `grep` can do all that stuff.

```
grep --recursive --ignore-case --files-with-matches "apple" mydir/
```

Comment: This only works with GNU grep, which is the default on Linux but not on Unix (AIX, HP-UX, Solaris, ...).